# Select particular String which comma separated in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I want to select a particular (3rd comma separate value) String that comma-separated in XSLT.

Input:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC, 2, 2, 4, 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VSD, , 4, 3, 9</td>
  </tr>
</tablr>
```

Outputshould be:

```
<root>
  <num>4</num>
  <num>3</num>
</root>
```

tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="td">
  <root>
    <num>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </num>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
```

My tried code does not give the correct value. I am using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `tokenize` function:

```
<xsl:variable name="fields" select="tokenize(text(), ',')" />
<xsl:value-of select="$fields[4]"/>
```